# How to add siblings to a parent element?

Tags: html, emmet

I'm using Sublime Text 2 with the Emmet plug-in.

This is the target HTML:

```
</html
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my current snippet :

```
html>head>title
```

Which off course does not add the `<body>` element.

I tried using the sibling abbreviation at the end like this:

```
html>head>title+body
```

However, the `<body>` tag is now added as a sibling to the `<title>` element instead of the `<head>` element.

How can I update my snippet so it adds the sibling to the parent element instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Solution.

```
(head>title>)html>body
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I know this was answered now and I have accepted the first answer which worked for me but for completness I wanted to add the link to the actual documentation I finally found as well as another alternative to the grouping abbreviation.

As I didn't know what the character commands were called I was unable to find the documentation on them at first.

However, after some extended research (thank you google) I finally found that they are called `abbreviations`.
Ones I found that I was also able to find the [**abbreviation syntax documentation**](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/) quite quickly.

After reading the documentation I found that there was 2 ways of solving my problem.

I can use the [**Climb-up**](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#climb-up-) abbreviation `^`, similar to this:

```
html>head>title^body
```

Or I can use the [**Grouping**](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#grouping-) abbreviation `()` to group your sets and then use the standard [**Sibling**](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#sibling-) abbreviation `+` as usual, similar to this:

```
html>(head>title)+body
```

Using the grouping abbreviation was also what [**Nathan Lee's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441198/448144) suggested and which I accepted.

Both will generate this output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If there is any benefit in using one of the other I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @François Wahl for further knowledge sharing. 

+1 from me, I Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
html>(head>title)(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to use html:5 within the Koan line (bottom line). That translates to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```